# R : Faster way to repeat an array along a dimension?

Tags: r, arrays, rep

Suppose i have an array `z` given by :

```
z = array(runif(100*50*200),c(100,50,200))
```

Is there a faster way to do :

```
dim(z) = c(100,50,1,200)
z = z[,,rep(1,300),]
```

Note that this is an exemple, the new dimension where i want to repeat the array is not always the 3rd, and the starting dimension of the array is not always 3.

`profvis::profvis()` only shows that the Garbage collector takes a certain time in the computation, but it does not show other internals..

It might be an allocation issue, although i'm not shure why it takes that kind of time. I have several of those very basic calls in my code, and 95% of my runtime is spend there.. So even if it's unavoidable, can you explain to me why is it so long ?

Comment: I'd expect the time is spent with memory management. I'd try to avoid this operation.

Comment: Yeah this is why I am looking for a replacement.

Comment: Not replace, avoid! What are you using the results for? Maybe there you could change the approach.

Comment: I dont think so, sadly...